# Logstash eventlog filter

Tags: logstash, event-log, elastic-stack

I need to filter error messages from microsoft eventlogs from logstash. ELK is running on ubunu 14.04 machine

logstash configuration

```
input {
   tcp {
     port => 5045
     type => 'eventlog'

   }
}
filter{

if [type] == 'eventlog' {
    if [Severity] == "ERROR" {
    mutate {
      add_tag => "error"
    }
  }
}


}
output {

  elasticsearch {
         hosts => ["IP_ADDRSS:9200"]
      }

   if "error" in [tags]{

   stdout { codec => 'rubydebug' }
}
}
```

But still I am getting thousands of eventlogs from which I can't filter out the error logs.
How to effectively filter error logs from all type of eventlogs?

Answer (score 0):

How are you ingesting the data? Not clear from the input configuration. If you use [Winlogbeat](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/beats/winlogbeat), filtering should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

There was no tag named "Severity:ERROR". So I added codec => "json" in tcp input. Now there is error tag in log. So I can filter it out.